# Feeding the output of one task into another in WDL

Tags: wdl, docker

Hi there I'm new to WDL and I need to complete a two-step workflow,

Basically, what I need to do is to extract and merge two reads dataset (forward and reverse) for a sample and pass the merged, uncompressed file to a different tool for genome inference. I'm able to complete the first step with no major issues; however, when it comes to get my output to the next task I'm facing some problems. Below a copy of the workflow I wrote

```
version 1.0

workflow step2 {
    input {
        String PANGENIE_CONTAINER = "overcraft90/eblerjana_pangenie:2.0.1"
        
        File FORWARD_FASTQ # compressed R1
        File REVERSE_FASTQ # compressed R2
        String NAME = "sample" # how to loop over samples' name in numerical order (maybe grub names' prefix)!?

        File PANGENOME_VCF # input vcf with variants to be genotyped
        File REF_GENOME # reference for variant calling
        File FASTQ_FILE # sample's FASTQ
        String VCF_PREFIX = "genotype" # string to attach to a sample's genotype
        String EXE_PATH = "/app/pangenie/build/src/PanGenie" # path to PanGenie executable in Docker

        Int CORES = 24 # number of cores to allocate for PanGenie execution
        Int DISK = 300 # storage memory for output files
        Int MEM = 100 # RAM memory allocated
    }

    call reads_extraction_and_merging {
        input:
        in_container_pangenie=PANGENIE_CONTAINER,
        in_forward_fastq=FORWARD_FASTQ,
        in_reverse_fastq=REVERSE_FASTQ,
        in_label=NAME, #later can be plural
        in_cores=CORES,
        in_disk=DISK,
        in_mem=MEM
    }

    call genome_inference {
        input:
        in_container_pangenie=PANGENIE_CONTAINER, # not sure whether Docker needs to be re-run
        in_pangenome_vcf=PANGENOME_VCF,
        in_reference_genome=REF_GENOME,
        in_executable=EXE_PATH,
        fastq_file=FASTQ_FILE,
        prefix_vcf=VCF_PREFIX,
        in_cores=CORES,
        in_disk=DISK,
        in_mem=MEM
    }

    output {
        File sample = reads_extraction_and_merging.fastq_file
        File genotype = genome_inference.vcf_file
    }
}

task reads_extraction_and_merging {
    input {
        String in_container_pangenie
        File in_forward_fastq
        File in_reverse_fastq
        String in_label
        Int in_cores
        Int in_disk
        Int in_mem
    }
    command <<<
        cat ~{in_forward_fastq} ~{in_reverse_fastq} | gzip -dc > ~{in_label}.fastq
        cp ~{in_label}.fastq /home/mat/cromwell-executions/step2/
    >>>
    output {
        File fastq_file = "~{in_label}.fastq"
    }
    runtime {
        docker: in_container_pangenie
        memory: in_mem + " GB"
        cpu: in_cores
        disks: "local-disk " + in_disk + " SSD"
    }
}

task genome_inference {
    input {
        String in_container_pangenie
        File in_reference_genome
        File in_pangenome_vcf
        String in_executable
        String prefix_vcf
        File fastq_file
        Int in_cores
        Int in_disk
        Int in_mem
    }
    command <<<
        echo "vcf: ~{in_pangenome_vcf}" > /app/pangenie/pipelines/run-from-callset/config.yaml
        echo "reference: ~{in_reference_genome}" >> /app/pangenie/pipelines/run-from-callset/config.yaml
        echo $'reads:\n sample: ~{fastq_file}' >> /app/pangenie/pipelines/run-from-callset/config.yaml
        echo "pangenie: ~{in_executable}" >> /app/pangenie/pipelines/run-from-callset/config.yaml
        echo "outdir: /app/pangenie" >> /app/pangenie/pipelines/run-from-callset/config.yaml
        cd /app/pangenie/pipelines/run-from-callset
        snakemake --cores ~{in_cores}
    >>>
    output {
        File vcf_file = "~{prefix_vcf}.vcf"
    }
    runtime {
        docker: in_container_pangenie
        memory: in_mem + " GB"
        cpu: in_cores
        disks: "local-disk " + in_disk + " SSD"
        preemptible: 1 # can be useful for tools which execute sequential steps in a pipeline generating intermediate outputs
    }
}
```

I try to summarize what's going on. After getting my two reads dataset, merging them and unzipping the output to `~{in_label}.fastq`; I have to get this new file and feed it to the next task, so my idea was to copy it to a directory and form there get its path in the ***.json*** I use to run the WDL with Cromwell. First of all, I believe it might not be the right way to do it and if it is the case what should I do instead? Secondly, is there anything else in the code which might be changed? For instance, I realised I cannot use `bgzip` to speed up the unzipping step taking advantage of multiple threads; this will be useful when scaling to multiple samples.
Thanks in advance!